# Testing of x64 project: inheritance issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, inheritance, 64-bit

I have a x64 project in Visual Studio 2010 with only one type inside:

```
public interface IDummy
{
    void Work();
}
```

I create a simple any CPU unit test project, where I implement the interface:

```
class MyDummy: IDummy
{
    public void Work()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Work");
    }
}
```

, and create a test:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WorkTest()
    {
        new MyDummy().Work();
        Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
    }
```

And I get:

*Error loading bla-bla\TestProject\bin\Debug\UnitTest.dll: Unable to load the test container 'bla-bla\TestProject\bin\Debug\UnitTest.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Dummy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

Host runs tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine.

**How to solve the problem?**

Comment: There's multiple reasons why you might be getting this error here (in the Remarks section): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

MyDummy class must be moved to 3rd assembly (AnyCPU or x64) and it works. MS VS 11 works fine without that workaround.

Unfortunately, one more project will be required.